# laravel useCurrentOnUpdate issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table set up this way:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    });
}
```

When I run `desc` user from mysql:

```
Fieldname = updated_at   
Type = timestamp
Null = NO
KEY = ""
Default = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
Extra = ""
```

I do not see information for `useCurrentOnUpdate`, and when I update a row, the timestamp did not update as well.

According to Laravel:
->useCurrentOnUpdate()  Set TIMESTAMP columns to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when a record is updated.

but it does not looks like it works, or I use it incorrectly?

Comment: Look at `show create table user`. `desc` output is quite limited.

Comment: with "show create table user" the line for updated_at, it showed `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, does not seems to include [useCurrentOnUpdate]??

Comment: Which MySQL and Laravel version?

Comment: Is [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps) what you are after? Letting Laravel create the columns directly?

Comment: I am pretty ignorant about `useCurrent` and the other one. What do both do ? I search about them and it is a normal `Carbon::now()` when you store data or update... so why do you need to define `useCurrent` and `useCurrentOnUpdate` when creating the schema when Eloquent already solves this behind scenes without the need to define those columns ? You just do `$this->timestamps();`. Explain more please as I have never saw this...

Comment: Laravel version: Laravel Framework 7.22.4 Mysql Version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35

Comment: I do not use public $timestamps = false in my setup.

Comment: Why are you using `useCurrentOnUpdate` if when you save a record (update it) it will automatically update `updated_at` ? Also, `useCurrentOnUpdate` was added on `Laravel 8.36.0`, read the [changelog](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9cc8d846a10ae5bf3afb73df88ecec4e2693769e/CHANGELOG-8.x.md#added-23), so your version does not use that... It does not exist...

Comment: yes, i found out this is a version issue, when I use with Laravel 7x, it runs.. so it confused me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears only Laravel 8x support this, but you can call it with 7x...

You will need to update Laravel 8x for this feature.